# What is the exact list of Ansible setup min?

Tags: ansible

According to the Ansible documentation, the `setup` module is

> This module is automatically called by playbooks to gather useful variables about remote hosts that can be used in playbooks. It can also be executed directly by `/usr/bin/ansible` to check what variables are available to a host. Ansible provides many facts about the system, automatically.

And there are some parameters which include `gather_subset`.

> If supplied, restrict the additional facts collected to the given subset. Possible values: `all`, `min`, `hardware`, `network`, `virtual`, `ohai`, and `facter`. Can specify a list of values to specify a larger subset. Values can also be used with an initial `!` to specify that that specific subset should not be collected. For instance: `!hardware`,`!network`,`!virtual`,`!ohai`,`!facter`. If `!all` is specified then only the min subset is collected. To avoid collecting even the min subset, specify `!all`,`!min`. To collect only specific facts, use `!all`,`!min`, and specify the particular fact subsets. Use the filter parameter if you do not want to display some collected facts.

I want to know the exact list of fact that `min` subset would collect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on your environment and setup what is available and can be collected.

You could just have a short test with

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false

  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "min"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

and check the output, in example for a RHEL system the keys are

```yaml
_ansible_facts_gathered: true
ansible_apparmor:
  status: 
ansible_architecture: 
ansible_cmdline:
  BOOT_IMAGE: 
  LANG: 
  elevator: 
  quiet: 
  rhgb: 
  ro: 
  root: 
ansible_date_time:
  date: ''
  day: ''
  epoch: ''
  hour: 
  iso8601: ''
  iso8601_basic: 
  iso8601_basic_short: 
  iso8601_micro: ''
  minute: ''
  month: ''
  second: ''
  time: 
  tz: 
  tz_offset: ''
  weekday: 
  weekday_number: ''
  weeknumber: ''
  year: ''
ansible_distribution: 
ansible_distribution_file_parsed: 
ansible_distribution_file_path: 
ansible_distribution_file_search_string: 
ansible_distribution_file_variety: 
ansible_distribution_major_version: ''
ansible_distribution_release: 
ansible_distribution_version: ''
ansible_dns:
  nameservers:
  - 
  search:
  - 
ansible_domain: 
ansible_effective_group_id: 
ansible_effective_user_id: 
ansible_env:
  HISTCONTROL: 
  HISTSIZE: ''
  HOME: 
  HOSTNAME: 
  KRB5CCNAME: 
  LANG: 
  LESSOPEN: ''
  LOGNAME: 
  LS_COLORS: 
  MAIL: 
  PATH: 
  PWD: 
  SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED: ''
  SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED: ''
  SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE: ''
  SHELL: 
  SHLVL: ''
  SSH_CLIENT: 
  SSH_CONNECTION: 
  SSH_TTY: 
  TERM: 
  TZ: 
  USER: 
  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: 
  XDG_SESSION_ID: ''
  _:
ansible_fips:
ansible_fqdn:
ansible_hostname:
ansible_kernel:
ansible_kernel_version: ''
ansible_local: {}
ansible_lsb: {}
ansible_machine:
ansible_machine_id:
ansible_nodename:
ansible_os_family:
ansible_pkg_mgr:
ansible_proc_cmdline:
  BOOT_IMAGE:
  LANG:
  elevator:
  quiet:
  rhgb:
  ro:
  root:
ansible_python:
  executable:
  has_sslcontext:
  type:
  version:
    major: 
    micro: 
    minor: 
    releaselevel:
    serial:
  version_info:
  -
ansible_python_version:
ansible_real_group_id:
ansible_real_user_id:
ansible_selinux:
  config_mode:
  mode:
  policyvers:
  status:
  type:
ansible_selinux_python_present:
ansible_service_mgr:
ansible_ssh_host_key_ecdsa_public:
ansible_ssh_host_key_ed25519_public:
ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public:
ansible_system:
ansible_system_capabilities:
- ''
ansible_system_capabilities_enforced: ''
ansible_user_dir:
ansible_user_gecos:
ansible_user_gid:
ansible_user_id:
ansible_user_shell:
ansible_user_uid:
ansible_userspace_architecture:
ansible_userspace_bits: ''
gather_subset:
- min
module_setup: true
```

For `min` the [/ansible/modules/setup.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/setup.py) tries to gather information from

```py
minimal_gather_subset = frozenset(['apparmor', 'caps', 'cmdline', 'date_time',
                                   'distribution', 'dns', 'env', 'fips', 'local',
                                   'lsb', 'pkg_mgr', 'platform', 'python', 'selinux',
                                   'service_mgr', 'ssh_pub_keys', 'user'])
```

so that can be considered as

> the exact list of fact that `min` subset would collect.

As one can see, blocks of the information are coming from different modules, in example for `ansible_distribution` from [facts/system/distribution.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/distribution.py).

In my case in example, the module for `ansible_env`, [facts/system/env.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/env.py) will create keys which can not be found in any other environment.

For more background information of what is collected for specific environments and setups you have a look into [/ansible/module_utils/facts](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts).

**Further Q&A**

- [How Ansible `gather_facts` and sets variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71043335/6771046)
- [Getting full name of the OS using `ansible_facts`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034832/getting-full-name-of-the-os-using-ansible-facts/71035723#71035723)

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"**I want to know the exact list of facts that the "min" subset would collect.**"*

A: Run the module separately by *ansible*. You'll see the list of the *facts* collected by this module

```sh
shell> ansible localhost -m setup -a 'gather_subset=min'
```

---

As a side note, the facts differ among the systems. For example, compare the collected minimal facts among FreeBSD and Ubuntu

```sh
shell> grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="FreeBSD 13.0-RELEASE"
```

Store the output in a file

```sh
shell> ansible localhost -m setup -a 'gather_subset=min' > /scratch/freebsd.json
shell> cat /scratch/freebsd.json
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
```

Remove 'localhost | SUCCESS => ` from the file

```sh
shell> cat /scratch/freebsd.json
{
    "ansible_facts": {
```

Create a file with the keys (variables) only

```sh
shell> cat freebs.json | jq '.ansible_facts | keys[]' > freebsd_keys.txt
```

Repeat the procedure in Ubuntu and create ubuntu_keys.txt

```sh
shell> grep DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

Diff the files

```sh
shell> diff ubuntu_keys.txt freebsd_keys.txt
3d2
< "ansible_cmdline"
6,8d4
< "ansible_distribution_file_parsed"
< "ansible_distribution_file_path"
< "ansible_distribution_file_variety"
25d20
< "ansible_machine_id"
29d23
< "ansible_proc_cmdline"
44,45d37
< "ansible_system_capabilities"
< "ansible_system_capabilities_enforced"
52d43
< "ansible_userspace_architecture"
```

---

There are also differences among the Linux distributions. For example, Ubuntu 20.04 and Centos 8

```sh
shell> diff ubuntu_keys.txt centos_keys.txt
38d37
< "ansible_ssh_host_key_ecdsa_public_keytype"
40d38
< "ansible_ssh_host_key_ed25519_public_keytype"
42d39
< "ansible_ssh_host_key_rsa_public_keytype"
```