# 'gather_facts' seems to break 'set_fact' and 'hostvars'

Tags: ansible, timestamp, ansible-facts, hostvars

I am using `set_fact` and `hostvars` to pass variables between plays within a playbook. My code looks something like this:

```yaml
- name: Staging play
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: hostname
      prompt: "Enter hostname or group"
      private: no
    - name: vault
      prompt: "Enter vault name"
      private: no
    - name: input
      prompt: "Enter input for role"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        target_host: "{{ hostname }}"
        target_vault: "{{ vault }}"
        for_role: "{{ input }}"

- name: Execution play
  hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['target_host'] }}"
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - "vault/{{ hostvars['localhost']['target_vault'] }}.yml"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: target_role
      vars:
        param: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['for_role'] }}"
```

This arrangement has worked without issue for months. However, our environment has changed and now I need to take a timestamp and pass that to the role as well as the other variable, so I made the following changes (denoted by comments):

```yaml
- name: Staging play
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes # Changed from 'no' to 'yes'
  vars_prompt:
    - name: hostname
      prompt: "Enter hostname or group"
      private: no
    - name: vault
      prompt: "Enter vault name"
      private: no
    - name: input
      prompt: "Enter input for role"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        target_host: "{{ hostname }}"
        target_vault: "{{ vault }}"
        for_role: "{{ input }}"
        current_time: "{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}" # Added fact for current time

- name: Execution play
  hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['target_host'] }}"
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - "vault/{{ hostvars['localhost']['target_vault'] }}.yml"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: target_role
      vars:
        param: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['for_role'] }}"
        timestamp: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['current_time'] # Passed current_time to 
        Execution Play via hostvars
```

Now, when I execute, I get the error that the `vault` hostvars variable is undefined in the Execution Play. After some experimenting, I've found that setting `gather_facts: yes` in the Staging Play is what is triggering the issue.

However, I need `gather_facts` enabled in order to use `ansible_time_date`. I've already verified via `debug` that the facts are being recorded properly and can be called by `hostvars` within the Staging Play; just not in the following Execution Play. After hours of research, I can't find any reasoning for why gathering facts in the Staging Play should affect `hostvars` for the Execution Play or any idea on how to fix it.

At the end of the day, all I need is the current time passed to the included role. Anyone who can come up with a solution that actually works in this use case wins Employee of the Month. Bonus points if you can explain the initial issue with `gather_facts`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, I had to reinvent the wheel a bit, but came up with a much cleaner solution. I simply created a default value for a timestamp in the role itself and added a setup call for date/time at the appropriate point, conditional on there being no existing value for the variable in question.

```yaml
- name: Gather date and time.
  setup:
    gather_subset: date_time
  when: timestamp is undefined and ansible_date_time is undefined
```

I was able to leave `gather_facts` set to `no` in the dependent playbook but I still have no idea why setting it to `yes` broke anything in the first place. Any insight in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> *... if you can explain the initial issue with `gather_facts` ... Any insight in this regard would be appreciated.*

This is caused by [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) and because Ansible do not "overwrite or set a new value" for a variable. So it will depend on when and where they become defined.

You may test with the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false

  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_facts }}" # will be {} only 

  - name: Gather date and time only
    setup:
      gather_subset:
        - 'date_time'
        - '!min'

  - name: Show Gathered Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}" # from hostvars['localhost'] again
```

and "try to break it" by adding

```yaml
  - name: Set Fact
    set_fact:
      ansible_date_time:
        date: '1970-01-01'

  - name: Show Facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost'] }}"
```

Just like to note that for your use case you should use

```yaml
  gather_subset:
     - 'date_time'
     - '!min'
```

since your are interested in `ansible_date_time` only. See [what is the exact list of Ansible setup min?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046).

Be also aware of [caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) since "*When created with `set_facts`’s cacheable option, variables have the high precedence in the play, but are the same as a host facts precedence when they come from the cache.*"