# Ansible variables and `gather_subset`

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

How do I find which ansible variable belong to which `gather_subset` group (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset)?

Following an example to get `ansible_hostname`. For which I basically did trial and error, but I still don't know if `system` is the only subset which includes `ansible_hostname` and moreover if it is the minimal subset.

```yaml
- name: Test gather facts
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset: ["system", "!all", "!min"]
  tasks:
    - name: Test delegation
        - name: Debug
          ansible.builtin.debug:
            msg:
              - "{{ ansible_facts }}"
              - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

of course I could also use a task like

```yaml
    - name: Filter and return only selected facts
      ansible.builtin.setup:
        filter:
          - hostname
```

to get only the variable `ansible_hostname`. The thing I don't like here is that it needs to be done as a task and not globally next to `gather_facts`.

Comment: "_if it is the minimal subset._": It will depend on your environment and setup what is available and can be collected. See in example [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046). That's the reason why there is not a full documented list currently. This will leave you with either testing things out and or do research within the respective source code.

Comment: "_I still don't know if system is the only subset which includes ansible_hostname_": Just for the `ansible_hostname` you may also have a look into [Ansible: How to get hostname without domain name?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/17139/6017) since "_You can use the magic variable `inventory_hostname`, the name of the host as configured in your inventory, as an alternative to `ansible_hostname` when fact-gathering is disabled._"