# Extracting number in text file to variable with Ansible

Tags: ansible, debian

There is a text file on the target node: `/etc/debian_version`:

```
8.6
```

In Ansible, I want to export this number to a variable, inside of a task.  Is there some Ansible built-in module that can accomplish this in a simple manner?

I use the below Ansible versions with Python 3.7:

```
ansible==4.10.0
ansible-core==2.11.12
```

Comment: Yes, gather_facts and the setup module are already doing this.

Comment: This information is already in the gathered facts for your node. If you still want to read that file,  see the `fetch` or `slurp` modules

Comment: Can [Getting ... of the OS using Ansible facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71034832/) give some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, the route I took was:

1. Install `lsb-release` using [`apt`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html)

   - It was not previously installed on my Debian
2. Then, thanks to [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts):

```yaml
when: ansible_facts["lsb"]["major_release"] | int == 11
```